# Setting up a pipeline through .gitlab-ci.yml file

Tags: pipelines, cicd

I have been trying to set up a complete pipeline for my deployment through GitLab. I have acquired some knowledge of YAML files. I have been able to set up a very novice yet a working pipeline that correctly deploys to my Sandbox. Now I want to include two jobs in .gitlab-ci.yml file. One regarding PMD check of my code base and other regarding setup audit trail(emailing everyday the manual changes in the configuration ).On my research I found that you can perform PMD checks through Static Application Security Testing(SAST).Below is the script that I have written.At the very last I have included the SAST job but it has error-ed out.
I want to perform PMD check on my code base but the SAST job fails while running openssl command. Any immediate help is highly appreciated.

```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
before_script:
  # Decrypt server key
  #- openssl aes-256-cbc -d -md -in assets/server.key.enc -out assets/server.key -k $SERVER_KEY_PASSWORD
  - openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha256 -salt -d -in assets/server.key.enc -out assets/server.key -k $SERVER_KEY_PASSWORD -pbkdf2

  # Set up environment variables
  - export CLIURL=https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/sfdx-linux-amd64.tar.xz  
  - export SFDX_AUTOUPDATE_DISABLE=false
  - export SFDX_USE_GENERIC_UNIX_KEYCHAIN=true
  - export SFDX_DOMAIN_RETRY=300
  - export SFDX_DISABLE_APP_HUB=true
  - export SFDX_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG
  - export DEPLOYDIR=mdapipkg
  - export TESTLEVEL=RunLocalTests

  #Create sfdx directory
  - mkdir sfdx

  #Install Salesforce CLI 
  - wget -qO- $CLIURL | tar xJ -C sfdx --strip-components 1
  - "./sfdx/install"
  - export PATH=./sfdx/$(pwd):$PATH

deploy: 
  script:
  # Authorize target deployment org
  - sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --instanceurl https://test.salesforce.com --clientid $SF_CONSUMER_KEY --jwtkeyfile assets/server.key --username $SF_USERNAME --setalias UAT 

  # Deploy to target deployment org and run unit tests
  #- sfdx force:mdapi:deploy --wait 10 --deploydir $DEPLOYDIR --targetusername UAT --testlevel $TESTLEVEL
  '''- mkdir mdapipkg
  - sfdx force:source:convert -r iberiaRM -d mdapipkg/ -x src/package.xml'''

  # Example shows how to run a check-only deploy
  - sfdx force:mdapi:deploy --checkonly --wait 10  --deploydir $DEPLOYDIR --targetusername UAT --testlevel $TESTLEVEL
include:
  - template: SAST.gitlab-ci.yml
sast:
  # Run only APEX and Secret scanning and run each analyzer as an isolated job
  variables:
    SAST_DEFAULT_ANALYZERS: "pmd-apex"
    SAST_DISABLE_DIND: "true"

``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Error:

Authenticating with credentials from job payload (GitLab Registry)
00:02
 $ openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha256 -salt -d -in assets/server.key.enc -out assets/server.key -k $SERVER_KEY_PASSWORD -pbkdf2
 /bin/bash: line 100: openssl: command not found
Uploading artifacts...
00:02
 WARNING: gl-sast-report.json: no matching files    
 ERROR: No files to upload                          
 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: Are you using one of the public shared runners that Gitlab provides, or do you have your own runner (shared, specific, or group)? The public shared runners should already have openSSL, but you'd need to use the package manager of whatever distro your own runner is using to install it if you're in control of the machine/container/vm that the runner is installed on.

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce recently [published](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/05/gitlab-salesforce-devops-made-easy.html) examples and Trailhead modules around using GitLab Pipelines for Salesforce DX projects.

The meat of the Pipelines setup is located [here](https://gitlab.com/sfdx/sfdx-cicd-template/blob/master/Salesforce.gitlab-ci.yml). The critical line is the first one, which sets the Docker image to be used as the execution context:

```
image: "node:latest"
```

The choice of image dictates what software is available to your script without further intervention. Note that further down, the example is actually using a different authentication strategy: [storing the auth URL](https://gitlab.com/sfdx/sfdx-cicd-template/blob/master/Salesforce.gitlab-ci.yml#L465), instead of using JWT.

You could follow their lead in using a Node image (which makes it possible to run Jest tests for Lightning Web Components), or select another Docker image of your choice which provides the `openssl` binary.

Alternately, use the distro's package manager to install `openssl`.

Note that you'll also need Java to run PMD. I've previously had success running PMD static analysis using [CircleCI's `node/latest` image](https://github.com/davidmreed/circleci-sfdx-examples/blob/master/static-analysis/config.yml), which you could use on Pipelines as it's just a public Docker image.

Comment: Thanks @David Reed for your answer.I tried using the image from CircleCi but it seems even that does not have the openssl. How can I use the distro's package manager to install openssl before my SAST job runs? Appreciate your help!

Comment: Also the Salesforce GitLab pipeline that you have mentioned is based on Packaged based deployment with Scratch Orgs and Currently we are neither using Packages nor Scratch Orgs for our release management.

Comment: Also if I use the CircleCI's image in my Gitlab Pipeline,is there a way I can directly run PMD by referring their image ? Sorry if i sound a little ignorant,I am new to this and have been honing up my skills.

Comment: That image definitely has `openssl`. I'm not sure why it's not appearing for you. It'd depend on what distro you're running, in Ubuntu you'd use `apt` to install the package. Someone might have built an image that includes PMD but I am not familiar with any of those.

Comment: @DavidReed : We have setup apex pmd using salesforce ant. and able to run it successfully local. How do we execute using git actions and show result .we are git premium license.

Comment: @DavidReed the link you gave didn't cover Pre & Post Destructive Changes .. Now how do we handle that? Happy to create a new question for this if needed