# GitLab pipeline template which includes pre & post destructive changes

Tags: package.xml, cicd, destructivechanges.xml, devopscenter, gitlab

I have read through the [Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/291877/setting-up-a-pipeline-through-gitlab-ci-yml-file). There are links pointing to the GitLab YAML template [here](https://gitlab.com/sfdx/sfdx-cicd-template/blob/master/Salesforce.gitlab-ci.yml) and [this outdated blog where trailhead no longer there](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/05/gitlab-salesforce-devops-made-easy). The lack of documentation for this GitLab integration to SF out there is frustrating af.

[DevOps Center Roadmap](https://github.com/orgs/forcedotcom/projects/4/views/1?filterQuery=gitlab) used to show 2nd half of 2023 for GitLab Integration but now under "Researching"

**Problems I see with the YAML template**

- template seems to be catered more towards **scratch orgs which I don't want to use.**
- template is way too long (almost 1000 lines of code with comments) why is there no example of how to create multiple small yaml files e.g. one for package development model, one for org development model, one for destructive changes?
- **Main Priority I need : How to include pre & post Destructive Changes inside the yaml in a best practice manner?**

I have managed to get the pre & post destructive changes working on the local machine via this command :

```
sfdx force:source:deploy --manifest manifest/package.xml --predestructivechanges manifest/destructiveChangesPre.xml --postdestructivechanges manifest/destructiveChangesPost.xml
```

However for the GitLab CICD YAML I'm stuck